# Control PDF presentations on Linux -- Samsung Galaxy Note 2

Tags: linux, remote-control, samsung-galaxy-note-2

I use LaTeX for all my presentations and therefore use a PDF viewer as my presentation software. I would like to be able to control my PDF presentations using my Galaxy Note 2. I'm looking for an app. to help me do that.

**Features I need**

- Navigate slides from phone.
- See slide preview on phone.
- Linux compatible.

**Bonus features**

- Ability to annotate slides using S-Pen.
- PDF-viewer agnosticism (i.e. works with most/all PDF viewers).
- Free.

Connectivity with either Bluetooth or WiFi would be acceptable.

Is there such an app. around? Barring that, is there a general purpose Linux remote around?

Answer (score 0):

Try gremote, it's good for presentation, but difficult to configure

Comment: Anyremote for Android

Comment: Can you edit your comment into your answer. Also, please try to add more details and links to the app in Google Play.